# Force Animation Completion Block to Run on Background Thread to Signal Semaphore

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, animation, objective-c-blocks

Hi so I'm trying to signal a semaphore from within a an animation completion block, but because the main thread is blocked by the semaphore, the completion block never even gets fired.

The signal cannot be called within the animation block as it will be called too soon.

I have tried wrapping the entire UIView animation block asynchronously in a background thread but that does not prevent the completion block from being dispatched to the main queue.

```
-(void)performAnimation {
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        // animation code   
    } completion: ^{
        dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
    }];

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Why do you want to force your method `performAnimation` to be synchronous, which also blocks the thread where it is invoked? In fact, there is no reason to do so. If you realize that, your initial issue won't even come up.

Comment: Because even if it was asynchronous, the code that calls     `performAnimation` would continue executing its code after the method call before the actual animations are done.

Comment: If you want to continue after the animation finished, you execute the "continuation" within the completion handler. That's the purpose of a completion handler ;)

Comment: Ahh. But the code that needs to be ran in the animation's completion handle contains variables of the calling class. But I did found a workaround using the animation's completion handle in the end :)

Comment: With *Blocks* (as opposed to functions), you can *capture* variables living outside the block, simply by *referencing* them in the block. You may read here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24456407/creating-a-method-to-perform-animations-and-wait-for-completion-using-a-semaphor/30563905#30563905

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by adding a completion block to be passed into the method so that this is the calling code:

```
[AnimatorClass performAnimationwithCompletion:^{
    // code that should be ran after the animation
}
```

and the new method:

```
- (void)performAnimationwithCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        // animation code
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (completion) {
            completion(); // now we can proceed to continue main thread execution
        }
    }];
}
```