# How to apply blink animation to a text inside TextView?

Tags: swift, text, textview, blink

In Swift, I try to make animation for just one character inside a text inside UITextView. But since the text is not a UIView, and since I cannot convert this text to UIView, I cannot animate it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please be more specific about your animation

Comment: @TLGCodin' I mean just animating the text, changing its alpha maybe. Like UIView.animate(withDuration.. etc.). But not the textView, only one character of the text

Comment: Check this out @AnthonSanthez https://stackoverflow.com/a/28246242/6178714

Comment: @Pastre thank you very much! That was exactly what I was looking for!