# Why is NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount set to 1

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, foundation, libdispatch

The reason for this question is because of the reactions to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48083343/is-the-following-a-safe-use-of-dispatch-set-target-queue).

I realized the understanding of the problem was not fully there as well as the reason for the question in the first place. So I am trying to boil down the reason for the other question to this one at it's core.

First a little preface, and some history, I know NSOperation(Queue) existed before GCD, and and they were implemented using threads before dispatch queues.

The next thing is that you need to understand is that by default, meaning no "waiting" methods being use on operations or operation queues (*just a standard "addOperation:"*), an NSOperation's main method is executed on the underlying queue of the NSOperationQueue **asynchronously** (*e.g. dispatch_async()*).

To conclude my preface, I'm questioning the purpose of setting NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1 in this day and age, now that the underlyingQueue is actually the main GCD serial queue (*e.g. the return of dispatch_get_main_queue()*).

If NSOperationQueue.mainQueue already executes it's operation's main methods serially, why worry about maxConcurrentOperationCount at all?

**To see the issue of it being set to 1, please see the example in the referenced question.**

Answer (score 4):

It's set to 1 because there's no reason to set it to anything else, and it's probably slightly better to keep it set to 1 for at least three reasons I can think of.

#### Reason 1

Because `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue`'s `underlyingQueue` is `dispatch_get_main_queue()`, which is serial, `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue` is effectively serial (it could never run more than a single block at a time, even if its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` were greater than 1).

We can check this by creating our own `NSOperationQueue`, putting a serial queue in its `underlyingQueue` target chain, and setting its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to a large number.

Create a new project in Xcode using the macOS > Cocoa App template with language Objective-C. Replace the `AppDelegate` implementation with this:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue;
    dispatch_queue_t serialQueue;
    NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    concurrentQueue = dispatch_queue_create("q", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("q2", nil);
    operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

    // concurrent queue targeting serial queue
    //dispatch_set_target_queue(concurrentQueue, serialQueue);
    //operationQueue.underlyingQueue = concurrentQueue;

    // serial queue targeting concurrent queue
    dispatch_set_target_queue(serialQueue, concurrentQueue);
    operationQueue.underlyingQueue = serialQueue;

    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        NSOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            NSLog(@"operation %d starting", i);
            sleep(3);
            NSLog(@"operation %d ending", i);
        }];
        [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
    }
}

@end
```

If you run this, you'll see that operation 1 doesn't start until operation 0 has ended, even though I set `operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 100. This happens because there is a serial queue in the target chain of `operationQueue.underlyingQueue`. Thus `operationQueue` is effectively serial, even though its `maxConcurrentOperationCount` is not 1.

You can play with the code to try changing the structure of the target chain. You'll find that if there is a serial queue anywhere in that chain, only one operation runs at a time.

But if you set `operationQueue.underlyingQueue = concurrentQueue`, and do **not** set `concurrentQueue`'s target to `serialQueue`, then you'll see that 64 operations run simultaneously. For `operationQueue` to run operations concurrently, the entire target chain starting with its `underlyingQueue` must be concurrent.

Since the main queue is always serial, `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue` is effectively always serial.

In fact, if you set `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount` to anything but 1, it has no effect. If you print `NSOperationQueue.mainQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount` after trying to change it, you'll find that it's still 1. I think it would be even better if the attempt to change it raised an assertion. Silently ignoring attempts to change it is more likely to lead to confusion.

#### Reason 2

`NSOperationQueue` submits up to `maxConcurrentOperationCount` blocks to its `underlyingQueue` simultaneously. Since the `mainQueue.underlyingQueue` is serial, only one of those blocks can run at a time. Once those blocks are submitted, it may be too late to use the `-[NSOperation cancel]` message to cancel the corresponding operations. I'm not sure; this is an implementation detail that I haven't fully explored. Anyway, if it is too late, that is unfortunate as it may lead to a waste of time and battery power.

#### Reason 3

As with mentioned with reason 2, `NSOperationQueue` submits up to `maxConcurrentOperationCount` blocks to its `underlyingQueue` simultaneously. Since `mainQueue.underlyingQueue` is serial, only one of those blocks can execute at a time. The other blocks, and any other resources the `dispatch_queue_t` uses to track them, must sit around idly, waiting for their turns to run. This is a waste of resources. Not a big waste, but a waste nonetheless. If `mainQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount` is set to 1, it will only submit a single block to its `underlyingQueue` at a time, thus preventing GCD from allocating resources uselessly.